# tf.exe workspaces "Unable to determine the source control server"

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am getting the following message from the build server:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The working folder C:\TFSBuildAgent\_work\8\s is already in use by the workspace ws_8_18;Project Collection Build Service (TEAM FOUNDATION) on computer MYSERVER02.
at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Server.Repository.CreateWorkspace(Workspace workspace)
```

I have logged onto Server MYSERVER02 and am trying to delete the workspace ws_8_18 by running one of the documented commands for [tf.exe workspaces](https://www.visualstudio.com/da-dk/docs/tfvc/workspaces-command):

> tf.exe workspaces remove:*
>
> tf.exe workspaces remove:ws_8_18
>
> tf.exe workspaces remove:ws_8_18 /collection:"http://myserver/projectcollection"

None seem to work and I get the error message:

> Unable to determine the source control server.

How do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

> tf.exe workspaces /collection:"http://myserver/projectcollection" remove:ws_8_18

i.e ensuring the project collection comes before the remove command.